# Как можно оптимизировать этот код? (16 задание Егэ)

Tags: python

mАлгоритм вычисления значения функции F(n), где n – натуральное число, задан следующими соотношениями:
`F(n) = n*n + 3*n + 9`, при `n ≤ 15`
`F(n) = F(n-1) + n - 2`, при `n > 15`, кратных 3
`F(n) = F(n-2) + n + 2`, при `n > 15`, не кратных 3

Определите количество натуральных значений `n` из отрезка `[1; 1000]`, для которых все цифры значения F(n) чётные.

```
def F(n):
    if n <= 15:
        return  n*n + 3*n + 9
    elif n > 15 and n % 3 == 0:
        return F(n-1) + n - 2
    elif n > 15 and n % 3 != 0:
        return F(n-2) + n + 2

def is_even(value):
    return all(d % 2 == 0 for d in [int(d) for d in str(value)])


evens = [val for val in range(1, 1001) if is_even(F(val)) is True]
k = 0
for even in evens:
    k += 1
    print(k,'{} (F = {})'.format(even, F(even)))
```

Comment: вычисляя F(n) использовать уже сохраненное значение F(n-1), что бы не пришлось вычислять одно и то же значение многократно.

Comment: Можно попробовать так кешировать результат функции: `import functools` и добавить декоратор `@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)` к `def F(n):` -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/14731729/5909792

Answer (score 1):

Смотря в каком смысле оптимизировать. Например, в задании не требуется перечислять эти числа, достаточно посчитать их количество, например, так:

```
print(sum(map(is_even, map(F, range(1, 1001)))))
```